# Shuffle sort - Fisher Yates, why cant I find random number between 0 and N-1?

Tags: sorting, random, shuffle

While studying Shuffle sort, I learnt Fisher Yates solution. It loops for 0 to array length and finds a random number between 0(inclusive) and the loop index (inclusive) and **NOT 0 and N-1**. Finding a random number between 0 and N-1 does not give a random solution. But I couldn't find the reason for the same.

```
public static void sort(Comparable[] a){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++){ 

        int r = StdRandom.uniform(i+1); 
        // why cant this be a.length

        exch(a, i, r);

    }
}
```

StdRandom.uniform(i+1) returns returns random number between 0 and i (both inclusive)

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you told us what language this is (clearly some C variant, but which?)

Comment: Um...@LeeDanielCrocker That's Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you can't generate each sequence with equal probability with your approach of choosing r between 0 to n-1.

Example:
Consider n=3 for set {a,b,c}
Total possible outcome = 3!
Now considering perfect random generator, possible swap results that it will generate, with their corresponding shuffled sets are as->

1. 0 1 2    {a,b,c}
2. 0 2 1    {a,b,c}
3. 1 0 2    {a,b,c}
4. 1 2 0    {a,c,b}
5. 2 0 1    {b,a,c}
6. 2 1 0    {a,b,c}

Clearly not covering all outcomes, which will not be the case with actual implementation of Fisher Yates.

Answer (score 0):

If you only select from 0 to N-1, then you can NEVER choose the last number in the array. It's therefore not completely random.

You can predict that the last number WILL DEFINITELY be out of place at least.

I know that that doesn't mean you can predict the entire sequence, but it does mean that there isn't complete randomness in the system.

Comment: ok, my bad. I actually wanted to know that if I used random between 0 to N (both inclusive), its still isn't considered completely random (Algorithms course - coursera). Can you help me understand this?